# Efficient string splitting on first match using data.table

Tags: r, data.table, stringi

I have data of the following structure:

```
require(data.table)
dt = data.table(c('string1: val1', 'gnistr2: val2', 'ingstr3: :::!val3', 'gtrins4: val4'))

> dt
                  V1
1:     string1: val1
2:     gnistr2: val2
3: ingstr3: :::!val3
4:     gtrins4: val4
```

My goal is to separate the column **V1** using only the **first** delimiter match (`:`), hence resulting in a Nx2 table. Had the third entry not featured the delimiter in its "value"-part, I know perfectly well that `data.table`'s built-in `tstrsplit()` function would work like a charm. I do not seek to regex out additional delimiter occasions, please assume that  `:::!val3` is a valid entry for line 3.

The `stringi` library contains a neat function `stri_split_fixed()` that allows limiting the split into `n` components. I do have a working solution that capitalises on this (see the `stringi` call using `n=2`):

```
require(stringi)
dt1 = dt[, .(val = unlist(stri_split_fixed(V1, ':', n=2))), .(r = seq_along(V1))]
dt1[, var := paste0('COL', 1:.N), r]
dt1 = dcast(dt1, r ~ var, value.var = 'val')[, .(COL1, COL2)]

> dt1 (this is my preferred output)
      COL1      COL2
1: string1      val1
2: gnistr2      val2
3: ingstr3  :::!val3
4: gtrins4      val4
```

I do, however feel, that the whole `dcast` call introduces unnecessary overhead, and I suspect that I can reduce my runtime. For example, I believe that there must be a way to achieve the same solution by omitting `unlist` and working from list columns:

```
dt2 = dt[, .(listcol = stri_split_fixed(V1, ':', n=2)), .(r = seq_along(V1))][, .(listcol)]
> dt2
             listcol
1:     string1, val1
2:     gnistr2, val2
3: ingstr3, :::!val3
4:     gtrins4, val4
```

For an easier overview of the structure:

```
> dt2[[1]]
[[1]]
[1] "string1" " val1"  

[[2]]
[1] "gnistr2" " val2"  

[[3]]
[1] "ingstr3"   " :::!val3"

[[4]]
[1] "gtrins4" " val4"
```

Is there a way to **efficiently** merge `dt2` into the output presented by the first solution? My experience in working with list columns is limited. Perhaps there are even other, even quicker approaches that do not even involve list columns?

Thank you.

Comment: Not sure if this covers all scenarios, but maybe something like `dt[, tstrsplit(V1, "(?<=[^:]):(?=[^:])", perl=TRUE)]` ?

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
library(data.table)
setnames(dt[, tstrsplit(V1, ":\\s+")], c("COL1", "COL2"))[]
```

-output

```
      COL1     COL2
1: string1     val1
2: gnistr2     val2
3: ingstr3 :::!val3
4: gtrins4     val4
```

---

Or with `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
separate_wider_delim(dt, V1, delim = ": ", 
    names = c("COL1", "COL2"), too_few = "align_end")
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 × 2
  COL1    COL2    
  <chr>   <chr>   
1 string1 val1    
2 gnistr2 val2    
3 ingstr3 :::!val3
4 gtrins4 val4
```

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap a single call to `stri_split_fixed()`, using `simplify=T`, in `data.table()`;

```
data.table(dt[, stri_split_fixed(V1,":",2,simplify=T)])
```

Output:

```
        V1        V2
1: string1      val1
2: gnistr2      val2
3: ingstr3  :::!val3
4: gtrins4      val4
```